# Django - is there way to connect Cytoscape? (Not CytoscapeJs)

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-applications, cytoscape

I am looking a way to use Cytoscape library with Python via Django.
I would like to go to route and be able to click node and have an output.

I want this to be similar to this one video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8xBlilTV4w

I have represented this problem on image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h77P4.png)

How should I tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That video was done using Dash with plotly and Cytoscape.js.  I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this with Cytoscape desktop.  There is work underway to support linking between web applications and Cytoscape desktop using CyREST, but I'm not sure if solves your problem.